# Fermion boundary conditions vs projective representations

Tags: representation-theory, fermions, boundary-conditions

I have a basic confusion about the two different boundary conditions for a fermion around a compact direction, periodic versus anti-periodic.

We learn in a QM class that a fermion wavefunction picks up a minus sign under a $2\pi$ rotation. I think the statement of this fact is that the fermion is in a projective representation of $SO(3)$, hence phases appear in particular ways under the group operations.

If we choose periodic boundary conditions around some compact direction of spacetime, then rotating around that cycle by $2\pi$ does not give a minus sign. Somehow this should not be inconsistent with the facts about the representation of the fermion. How is this apparent difference in sign resolved?